# Replacing text within html element string

Tags: jquery, html, string, dom, object

I have a div `.content` with an HTML table as a JavaScript String. Within the `.content` element, there is a td `.quantity` I need to update the string.

I just tried this:

```
var content = $('.content').html();
content = $(content).parent().children('.quantity').text("6"); // []
content = $(content).parent().children('.quantity').text("6").html(); // null
```

I just want to output the string with the update value, kind of like a DOM based search and replace, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Within the .content element, there is a td .quantity I need to update
>   the string.

Try `find()` method:

```
var content = $('.content').html();
$(content).find('.quantity').text("6");
```

You can access it directly too:

```
$('.content').find('.quantity').text("6");
```

Comment: this kind of works its giving me `<td class="quantity>6</td>` but i need the entire table to go back into the `content` variable.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Reach out the parent table then but try using `find` method in similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
var content = $('.content table');
$('.quantity', content).text('6').end(); // will return `table`
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/uNQf9/2/)**

You can try this to get String

```
$('.quantity', content).text('6').end().parent().html();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/MYcCS/)

Comment: I need it returned as a string, how can I do that .html() does not work.

Comment: `$('.quantity', content).text('6').end();` is an object. I need it to be a string.